# How to prevent name clash with user defined properties

Tags: neo4j

I'm using neo4j (but probably this also applies to other databases). The user can give his own key/value pairs. But i also need to define some properties by the system. How do i prevent a name clash (on the key)? I could prefix all the system properties, but it seems a bit weird. Also i could make another node and put all the system properties there, but that might make for some difficult queries. What's a good way to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neo4jis property graph.
Basically, there is no magic there. You already mentioned all possible solutions.

From my perspective best solution is - add prefixes to user defined properties (for example `@`). This will keep queries simple enough, and doesn’t affect any performance problems.

Additionally, if this properties are only for READ and you are never going to run query against them, then you can look into storing JSON with user-defined data in your nodes:

```
SET n.user_data = ‘{“key”: “value”}’
```

Comment: I was thinking of prefixing system properties, but then the user can choose the prefix by accident. Prefixing user properties is much smarter! thanks

Comment: you can also prefix them by user-id if you want to avoid clashes between users.